# Crossings free path on a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Let $G(V, E)$ be a complete undirected graph and $p = v_1, \dots, v_\ell$ a path of unique arbitrary $\ell$ vertices of $V$. Each vertex of $V$ is a point in a two-dimensional discrete space (e.g., $v_i = (x, y)$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$).

Is it possible to find a path $p'$ that contains the same points of $p$ in a different order such that the following properties holds:

- every edge does not graphically intersect any other of $p'$;
- the starting and the ending point of $p'$ are the same of those of $p$?

I implemented the well-known [2-Opt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) but I'm not satisfied with its performance (see, e.g., Englert, Röglin and Vöcking, *Worst case and probabilistic analysis of the 2-Opt algorithm*, [pdf](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~englert/publications/tsp_soda07_full.pdf)).

Are there any known algorithms faster than the previous one that solve this problem?

Comment: In general is $2 <= n <= \lvert{V}\rvert$. I'm using 2-Opt not for solving (approximately) a TSP instance, but just because, given the route $p$ (not necessarily an Hamiltonian path), 2-Opt$(p)$ generates a path $p'$ without any crossing and with the same points of $p$. Thanks for helping, by the way :)

Comment: OK.  I edited the question to make the length of the path $\ell$, since there's such a strong association in graph theory that $n$ almost always means $|V|$. Sorry I've only been able to help with your question, rather than helping by answering it!

Comment: 1. I don't understand.  You can use 2-opt, but it is not a correct algorithm: it might fail to find a path $p'$ even when a path $p'$ does exist.  The fact that you suggest 2-opt as a solution makes me suspect I don't understand the problem.  2. Is $p'$ allowed to use any other vertex that wasn't used in $p$?  Or must $p'$ contain each of $v_1,\dots,v_\ell$ exactly once and avoid using any other vertex?  3. How do you want to measure performance?  By worst-case asymptotic running time?  If so, what's the running time of the best algorithm you know (e.g., of 2-opt) for this problem?

Comment: 1) The reason why I'm using 2-opt is "The main idea behind it is to take a route that crosses over itself and reorder it so that it does not." (cite Wikipedia, 2-opt). 2) No, $p'$ must be defined on the same points of $p$. You can see $p'$ as a permutation of $p$ with the only two constraints specified in the question. 3) Yes, I'm measuring performance by worst-case asymptotic running time. Actually, if I have well understood the paper cited in question, it's between $O(n^4)$ and $O(n^{10})$ (they made a probabilistic analyses on the number of steps). Thanks for helping :)